# How to add/ remove css class in parent/child element[divs] in angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8

I am working on Send money feature in a banking application. 
In this, the customer has to select a recipient from the recipient list and the selected recipient should be highlighted is the requirement.
Let's say there are 3 nested divs which contains each recipient information.

The problem I'm facing is when I select(click) on a recipient div I am not able to highlight it,

How do we do it angular 8?

```
<div class="parent">
<div 
class="cards-col col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" class="recipient-div"
*ngFor="let recipient of recipientsList"
(click)="selectedRecipient($event)">
    <form id="recipient-form-sendmoney-dummy" method="post">
        <div class="favourite-recipient" onclick="markFavoriteBene(this)" data-beneno="3"></div>
        <div class="recipient-card" onclick="viewRecipient(this)">
            <div class="recipient__avatar"><img class="profile-pic recipient__avatar" src="assets/img/user-img.jpg"></div>
            <h4 class="recipient__name spacer-8 recipient-beneview-content">{{recipient.name}} ({{recipient.name}})</h4>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

select-recipient.component.ts
This class includes some basic angular imports and noting much

```
selectedRecipient(e){
}
```

what do I add in this function so that I can highlight[add some css class for colour] the selected recipient out of many?

Or any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: a working code snippet should help us point you in right direction

Comment: what is the use of `selectedRecipient()` function? Is it used to select a particular recipient?

Comment: and you have to more careful about child click events. (when you clicked on parent div the child click events also will get triggered in that case)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight a selected or click div then you can use an index to determine which item has clicked.

HTML Change:

```
[ngClass]="i == selectedIndex ? 'selected' : ''" // for div element which you want to apply styles
```

TS Change:

```
selectedIndex : number;

selectedRecipient(data) {
  this.selectedIndex = data;
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) about exported values available:

```
                                    using this
                                     \/\/\/\/
*ngFor="let recipient of folders; let i = index"
```

[`Working_Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r7afhq)

Comment: one doubt, how does it know which index is selected after all the recipients are rendered, and when recipient is selected it adds class to that index? does angular remembers/stores loop indexes internally or something

Comment: @rahuldas updated the answer, pls check, `does angular remembers/stores loop indexes internally or something` - yes you can store index so will get to know about the current iteration

Comment: @rahuldas Updated answer with documentation link, feel free to check and let me know for any other queries

Comment: Thanks for the Doc Prashant. Proceed with the same solution

Comment: Just a thought. What if there was no "index" thing, How would I target the clicked div out of many similar divs and apply the class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

> Adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

The component template has a click event listener which will execute `toggleSelection()`. On the same element is `[ngClass]` which will only add the `highlight` class when the value of `selected` is `true`.

**your.component.html**

```html
<div
  (click)="toggleHighlight()"
  [ngClass]="{ 'highlight': selected }">
  Click to toggle class
</div>
```

The component class is where your logic to set the value of `selected` is executed inside of the `toggleSelection()` method.

**your.component.ts**

```js
...

selected: boolean;

toggleSelection() {
  this.selected = !this.selected;
}

...
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-be4cwu) demonstrating the concept.

Comment: Tried this, problem with this is when i click on any one recipient the highlight class gets applied to all the recepients

Comment: @rahuldas move the click handler to the child component instead of the parent or follow the approach by Prashant using the element index. Really depends on where the responsibility for the toggle should sit; parent or child component. Your code, your call :)